# Can't seem to break while loop properly. Comes up with an error message

Tags: python, while-loop, break

The code takes data from csv and reads up to row with no data- works well but code ends in error - break not working properly? Carries out necessary function of reading all data but it seems to continue through the while true statement past len(row) > 0 when it should be an empty row where len(row) == 0 - any ideas how to stop error message? Functionality is good but error message is obviously a tad annoying.

```
while True:  
    len(row) > 0
    row = csvFileArray[rowValue]  # row 
    x, y, z, l, m, n, p, q, r = row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8]

    x = float(x)
    y = float(y)
    z = float(z)
    l = float(l)
    m = float(m)
    n = float(n)
    p = float(p)
    q = float(q)
    r = float(r)

    y_axis = Vector((l, m, n))
    z_axis = Vector((p, q, r))

    x_axis = y_axis.cross(z_axis).normalized()

    M = Matrix((x_axis, y_axis, z_axis)).transposed()

    M = M.to_4x4()

    M.translation = scale * Vector((x, y, z))

    #test
    print(M)
    print(x_axis, y_axis, z_axis)
    bpy.ops.object.empty_add()
    mt = context.object
    mt.empty_display_type = 'ARROWS'
    mt.matrix_world = M

    rowValue = rowValue + 1

    if len(row) == 0:
        break
```

Comment: you're not doing anything with the result of `len(row) > 0`.  you might think there's an `if` statement there, but there isn't!  why not just move the `if` at the bottom to the top?

Comment: Hi, just tried that, I get a syntax error with the arrow pointing to 0 on the len(row) > 0 line

Answer (score 0):

Change the position of the break condition and change it to:

```
    if len(row) == 0:
        break
```

to

```
    if len(row) <= 0:
        break
```

Edited code:

```
while True:

    row = csvFileArray[rowValue]  # row 
    if len(row) <= 0:
        break
    x, y, z, l, m, n, p, q, r = row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8]

    x = float(x)
    y = float(y)
    z = float(z)
    l = float(l)
    m = float(m)
    n = float(n)
    p = float(p)
    q = float(q)
    r = float(r)

    y_axis = Vector((l, m, n))
    z_axis = Vector((p, q, r))

    x_axis = y_axis.cross(z_axis).normalized()

    M = Matrix((x_axis, y_axis, z_axis)).transposed()

    M = M.to_4x4()

    M.translation = scale * Vector((x, y, z))

    #test
    print(M)
    print(x_axis, y_axis, z_axis)
    bpy.ops.object.empty_add()
    mt = context.object
    mt.empty_display_type = 'ARROWS'
    mt.matrix_world = M

    rowValue = rowValue + 1
    # Printing the row variable might help in figuring out the error.
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but it still seems to run through to the: 'row = csvFileArray[rowValue]  # row ' line and gives an error which is strange

Comment: Did you update the while loop? If you are using 'while len(row) > 0:', set row to a non zero number before the loop.

Comment: As in set row to integer?

Comment: No, set it to a single element array.

Comment: What did you also mean by remove that line - remove the while loop line?

Comment: In each iteration, try to print the row variable, it will give more insight into the error.

Comment: Change while True : to while len(row)>0:

Comment: How would I set to single element array?

Comment: I'm still getting the same error unfortunately- an index error on the same line

Comment: Check it and let me know.

Comment: Still the same error with print(row) it prints the matrix fine. Again the code itself works I just dont understand why it ends in an error

Comment: row = csvFileArray[rowValue]  # row

Comment: 'list index out of range'

Comment: The new code should work fine, remove the print(row) line and check for indendations, sometimes tabs and spaces might get mixed up.

Comment: What do you mean replace with tabs or spaces? -New to python

Comment: Indentation should be either tabs or spaces. You should not use it simultaniously

Answer (score 0):

The second line `len(row)>0` is a redundant statement not doing anything.

I think when your program runs into a row with no entry on the third line of your code i.e. `row = csvFileArray[rowValue]`, it continues to assign this empty row to `row` and try to access indices of `row` beyond 0 in the following line, which gives error.

Try moving the last

```
    if len(row) == 0:
        break
```

to the line after `row = csvFileArray[rowValue]  # row` so its length gets checked immediately before you attempt to access indices.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but it still seems to run through to the: 'row = csvFileArray[rowValue]  # row ' line and gives an error which is strange

Comment: Can you please give the stack trace of the error message?